# Can't update data from axios and vue-python

Tags: python, vue.js, axios

I have problem when I want to update an element from my form.
here is my code:

```
<script setup>
    const updateSupply = async () => {
        console.log("Test");
        errors.value = ""
        try {
            await axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:49146/" + "supply");
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.response.status === 422) {
                for (const key in e.response.data.errors) {
                    errors.value = e.response.data.errors
                }
            }
        }
    };

const { destroySupply, updateSupply, updateClick } = useSupply();

const saveSupply = async () => {
  // console.log("Test");
  await updateSupply();
  // supply_id:this.supply_id,
};
</script>

<template>
<!-- Modal -->
  <CardBoxModal_JTO
    v-model="updateModalActive"
    title="Update supply"
    has-close
  >
    <form @submit.prevent="saveSupply">
      <CardBox>
        <FormField label="Noms & Email">
          <FormControl
            id="supply_name"
            v-model="form.supply_name"
            name="supply_name"
            :icon="mdiAccount"
            placeholder="name supply"
            required
          />
          <FormControl
            id="supply_email"
            v-model="form.supply_email"
            name="supply_email"
            type="email"
            :icon="mdiMail"
            placeholder="Email supply"
            required
          />
        </FormField>

        <!-- Buttons footer -->
        <BaseButtons class="flex justify-center">
          <BaseButton
            class="mr-2"
            type="submit"
            color="jt_orders"
            label="Update"
          />
          <BaseButton
            class="ml-2"
            type="reset"
            color="danger"
            outline
            label="Cancel"
          />
        </BaseButtons>
      </CardBox>
    </form>
  </CardBoxModal_JTO>


</template>
```

The Django code

```
# SupplyApi
@csrf_exempt
def supplyApi(request,id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        supplies = Supplies.objects.all()
        supplies_serializer = SupplySerializer(supplies,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(supplies_serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        supply_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        supplies_serializer = SupplySerializer(data=supply_data)
        if supplies_serializer.is_valid():
            supplies_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)
    elif request.method =='PUT':
        supply_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        supply = Supplies.objects.get(supply_id=supply_data['supply_id'])
        supplies_serializer = SupplySerializer(supply,data=supply_data)
        if supplies_serializer.is_valid():
            supplies_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Update")
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        supply = Supplies.objects.get(supply_id=id)
        supply.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully",safe=False)
```

Somehow i get this error `[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 527ms]`.
And the django server error :

```
IInternal Server Error: /supply
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\parsers.py", line 64, in parse
    return json.load(decoded_stream, parse_constant=parse_constant)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\json.py", line 31, in load
    return json.load(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rt-enterprises\OneDrive\RTSOFTT\PROJECTS\Python Projects\JT_ORDER-FILES\jt_orders\jt_orders_app\views.py", line 42, in supplyApi
    supply_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\parsers.py", line 66, in parse
    raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % str(exc))
rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

PS : Below is my code for the **`storeSupply`** which works very well.

```
<script>
const storeSupply = async (data) => {
        errors.value = ""
        try {
            await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:49146/" + "supply", data);
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.response.status === 422) {
                for (const key in e.response.data.errors) {
                    errors.value = e.response.data.errors
                }
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

What did I do wrong ?
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
First I changed the backend by adding:
`supply = Supplies.objects.get(supply_id=id)` in place of `supply = Supplies.objects.get(supply_id=supply_data["supply_id"])`.
Please see full code below
`Django code`

```
elif request.method == "PUT":
    supply_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    supply = Supplies.objects.get(supply_id=id)
    supplies_serializer = SupplySerializer(supply, data=supply_data)
    if supplies_serializer.is_valid():
       supplies_serializer.save()
       return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully", safe=False)
    return JsonResponse("Failed to Update")
```

then I modified the `storeSupply or updateSupply` function by

```
const updateSupply = async (id) => {
  console.log("Access successfully");
  await axios
    .put("http://127.0.0.1:49146/" + "supply/" + id, {
      supply_address: form.supply_address,
      supply_city: form.supply_city,
      supply_email: form.supply_email,
      supply_name: form.supply_name,
      supply_phone: form.supply_phone,
      supply_zip_code: form.supply_zip_code,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      // alert(response.data); Put toast here
      location.reload();
    });
};
```

and it works now without problem, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any data in your PUT request from your `Vue.js` component. In the `updateSupply` function, and `Django` view expects to parse JSON from the incoming request which is why you have this error.

lets try to include the data you want to update in the PUT request, for example:

```
const updateSupply = async () => {
    console.log("Test");
    errors.value = ""
    try {
        await axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:49146/" + "supply", form.value);
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.response.status === 422) {
            for (const key in e.response.data.errors) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your code and I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "status", e.response is undefined`

Comment: You welcome, try to get more info about the error with catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}

Comment: Even with the `catch(e) { console.error(e); }`, I couldn't get much. I tried this code

```const updateSupply = async () => {
        console.log("Accès avec succes");
        axios.put("http://127.0.0.1:49146/" + "supply",  {
        })
        .then((response) => {
            alert(response.data);
        });
  ```  }

 and it gives me error `Uncaught (in promise), [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 3057ms]`? Please help me, the Create, Read, Delete mothods are working fine, only the update method is missing.

Comment: It might be on the server-side. Debug your Django view to see why it's throwing a 500 error.

Comment: Thank you all. I used postman to perform the tests and everything works fine on the django side. Unless I have code that is not optimal. I'm new in Django and this is my very first project with this framework. The `create , delete, read` work very well except the `update` which makes me miserable. Please help me find a solution to my problem. I've been struggling with it for 2 weeks now. It must be a solution to this problem. Please help me.